# Can't open .py files in IDLE on desktop with Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, python-idle

I just upgraded from python 3.9.2 to python 3.10.2 (both 64-bit) on Windows 10 home premium.  I am now unable to open a .py file on the desktop with IDLE via right click -> edit with Idle 3.10.  There is no error message, it's just that nothing happens.  If I put the .py file into any other folder I can open it.  After moving it to another folder if I put a shortcut of the .py file on the desktop I can open it just fine.  Any ideas what may be happening?

Comment: Can you open files on your desktop from file-> open within IDLE?

Comment: I just checked and I can open a .py file on the desktop from within IDLE.  I just can't right click on the .py file and edit with IDLE

Comment: I just moved a file to desktop, right-clicked, and opened in IDLE 3.11.0a4 (which I have set as default.  No problem there.  However, only 3.11 was  while I have multiple versions installed.  Do you still have 3.9 installed, and if so, does it also appear with 3.10?  In any case, I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue46594 and mentioned this report also.

Comment: I had uninstalled all other versions of python.  My solution was to make double-clicking open with data\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat since I open in IDLE more than running directly.  I should probably be switching to pyCharm or something anyway